# How to subtract dates and accounting for null values?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a column that calculates the duration of seconds it takes from A to B in format hh:mm:ss. However, A and B may show null values in the data.

Let's say A=05:15:00 and B=naT, then the subtraction will return 5:15 seconds which is misleading and wrong in context due to B being infinity! How can I specify to only subtract columns B from A if **both** columns are NOT NULL?

This is the code I have:

```
df['A_to_B']=(df.B-df.A).dt.total_seconds()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python does not use null, but it does use a type called None to represent the absence of a value / type. So you would check if df.B and df.A are both not None, perhaps like this:

```
if (df.A is not None) and (df.B is not None):
    df['A_to_B'] = (df.B-df.A).dt.total_seconds()
```

Comment: Python perhaps, but pandas do have the value ```NaN```

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
df['A_to_B'] = np.where(df['A'].notna() & df['B'].notna(), 
                        (df['A'] - df['B']).dt.total_seconds(),
                        np.nan)
```

Sample data

```
         A        B
0 05:15:00      NaT
1      NaT 00:00:15
2 05:15:00 00:15:00
```

Output:

```
         A        B   A_to_B
0 05:15:00      NaT      NaN
1      NaT 00:00:15      NaN
2 05:15:00 00:15:00  18000.0
```